# How to restore SQL file generated by MySQLDump using command prompt

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL file generated by MySQLDump. How can I restore it via command prompt?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. get to bin directory of mysql using command prompt
2. log in to mysql
3. run source command with file parameter

Example :

```
cd C:\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -p
mysql> source c:\myfile.sql
```

Comment: You don't have to be in the MySQL bin directory if your system is sane, and by sane, I mean has the MySQL bin directory in the PATH.

Comment: I am using normal window cmd..And i tried this. But no results and no error.....

C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysql -uroot -ppassword mysql > source d:\admindb\
aar12.sql

Comment: well in third step, don't write "mysql >" :)

Comment: I am not getting any errors. But there is no update when i see in my query browser. The script works fine when executing manually in query browser. Tried this in cmd : C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysql -uroot -ppassword source d:\admindb\AAR12.sql

Comment: My .sql file looks encoded (or in binary form). So the above method gives lots of errors, is there any specific flag which I'll have to use?

Comment: how can i preserve comments while restoring using above command?

Answer (score 75):

Run this command (if the `mysql` executable isn't in your `PATH`, first go to the directory where the MySQL binary is installed, something like `\mysql\bin`):

```
mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < file.sql
```

(Note that there is no space between `-p` and the password)

Or if the file is gzipped (like my backups mostly are) then something like this:

```
gunzip file.sql.gz | mysql -u username -ppassword databasename
```

or on some systems it might be necessary to add the `-c` flag to gunzip, like so (to force it to output to stdout):

```
gunzip -c file.sql.gz | mysql -u username -ppassword databasename
```

Comment: This also works if you're doing anything remotely, just add the `--host` arg.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ mysql database < myfile.sql
```

OR

```
$ mysql database
mysql> source myfile.sql
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is:

```
mysql database_name < file.sql
```

See: [Using mysql in Batch Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)

Comment: I am using normal window cmd..And i tried this. But no results and no error..... C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysql -uroot -ppassword mysql > source d:\admindb\ aar12.sql

Comment: The syntax is as I wrote above. What you've done there is redirect the output of the `mysql` command a file called `source` in your working directory. (Your redirection arrow is pointing the wrong way, should be `<`, and you have too many parameters).

Answer (score 4):

Assume you are going to import `/home/abc.sql`
Run commands below:

```
cd /home    
mysql -u root -p
```

If table not exists:

```
mysql> create database abc;
```

Now use database `abc` and import `abc.sql`

```
mysql> use abc;
mysql> set names utf8;
mysql> source abc.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

From within MySQL command prompt, type

```
SOURCE file.sql
```