# Import MySQL database backup

Tags: mysql, import, database-backups

I want to import a MySQL database backup, I have searched through SO and find these two questions, [How to restore SQL file generated by MySQLDump using command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021062/how-to-restore-sql-file-generated-by-mysqldump-using-command-prompt) and [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql) very relevant. They seems to have answer but when i try these solutions `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql` on windows 10 mysql 10.1.37 I get following error

> Unknown database 'keepa<keepa.sql'
> Although i have given database present when i query `show databases;` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnm45.png)

I have created different databases names and sometime left it blank or put space between '<' symbol but does not succeed in this.
Please help me in this regard. Thank you

Edit:
as pointed out in comment i want to further clarify that.
I'm running it from same directory where the keepa.sql does exist and i have keepa database name already in db. in case of space between `keepa < keepa.sql` i grt error '<' is reserved for future use.

Comment: You need a `CREATE DATABASE \`keepa\`` either in the Backup file, or you have to manually create that database so the restore can put data into table within that database

Comment: 'keepa<keepa.sql' must be `keepa < keepa.sql`. the error should differ if there is any.

Comment: Also you should be running this command from the directory where keepa.sql is stored and must exit from mysql terminal.